# Где хранятся переменные класса? c++

Tags: c++, выделение-памяти, куча

Пусть будет вот такой класс:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
};
```

Где выделяется память под переменные объектов этого класса, если выделить его: а)без `new`, б)с оператором `new`? И если они хранятся в стеке в любом случае, то стоит ли вместо этого выделять переменные через оператор `new`, если мой класс будет содержать немало переменных и количество объектов класса будет исчисляться сотнями?

Comment: Условие `И если они хранятся в стеке в любом случае` - невыполнимо. Значит у вас вопроса нет. Задайте вопрос чётко.

Comment: Стоит ли использовать оператор ```new``` в классе для того, чтобы переменные хранились в куче? Или достаточно создавать объект в куче для того, чтобы переменные не хранились в стэке?

Comment: Переменные класса занимают часть памяти объекта. И они неразделимы с ним. При вызове `new A` выделится память под всю структуру, со всеми переменными. Расположите в объект стеке - эти переменные будут там-же.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные объявленные в классе - члены класса. Память выделяется сразу под объект класса, а не под каждый член. В выделенной под объект класса памяти переменные располагаются последовательно в порядке их объявления в классе.
Конкретно в вашем случае объект класса будет занимать ровно столько байт, сколько суммарно занимают переменные.
В общем случае:

- добавляются указатели на таблицу виртуальных функций (если есть)
- память занимаемая членами базовых классов (если класс наследуется от кого-то)
- выравнивание для маленьких типов (зависит от платформы)
  и др.
  Расположение в памяти зависит от того, где расположен объект этого класса.

```
A GlobalObject;  // глобальный объект - в памяти программы

void foo(void)
{
    A LocalObject; // локальный объект - на стеке
    A* ptr = new A;  // динамический объект - в куче
    delete ptr;
}

int main()
{  // константные и статические объекты - в памяти программы
  constexpr A ConstObject{ 0, 1, 2.0}; 
  static A StaticObject;
}
```

Расположение в памяти взаимозависимо с временем жизни объектов.
Не путать с областью видимости.

Comment: Что такое «память программы»?

Comment: Имел ввиду блок памяти, выделяемый 1 раз при запуске программы под данные с глобальным временем жизни (глобальные переменные, статические и т.д.). Просто в вопросе про "где размещаются переменные" рассказывать про соглашение по выделению памяти операционной системой при запуске программы - многовато.

Comment: ОК, но разве под константные объекты блок памяти выделяется один раз при запуске программы?

Comment: С константными объектами сложнее. Например для текстовых констант - да. Если какая-то константа используется локально и один раз, то скорее всего под неё вообще не будет выделено памяти, она будет просто в коде. Но вообще конечно зависит от времени жизни. Думаю, на это ещё сильно влияет оптимизации компилятора.